# when does "active today" appear?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes some old questions appear and are called "active today" , without any visible signs how they [were activated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43610/question-about-de-broglie-waves).

I thought activation could happen by editing or community rotating it forward. What is the other method?

In this particular case no edits and no community; the questioner has not been seen since the days of his question.

Answer (score 1):

Our good friend [Community ♦](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) bumps old posts that are "unanswered". An "answered" post is one that has at lease one answer with at least one upvote (or accept)

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/178438 as well.

Comment: but when it does that the author becomes "community" this is not the case in the link I provide.

Comment: @annav: On the main page, it shows Community (http://i.stack.imgur.com/LLkXi.png). When Community _edits_ a post, it has nothing to do with the auto bumping. That's when an anonymous user suggests an edit. And _then_, it shows up as the editor.

Comment: thanks, did not notice that